# Flutter permission_handler IOS location

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to know if the user selected when in use or always (location permissions).

I use this code on an IOS 13 simulator

```
static Future<PermissionStatus> checkPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.locationAlways);
    return permission;
  }
```

This returns "GRANTED", I would like it to return "always" or "when_in_use".

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you have figured this out by now, but the issue is that you were asking for the status of `locationAlways` -- which would be granted or denied for that specific permission. To find out what the status is of `locationWhenInUse`, you would have to ask for that directly.

`permission_handler` has changed since this question was asked, but for your situation you could use it like this:

```dart
  Future<String> checkPermissions() async {
    PermissionStatus whenInUse = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.status;
    if (whenInUse == PermissionStatus.granted) return "when_in_use";

    PermissionStatus always = await Permission.locationAlways.status;
    if (always == PermissionStatus.granted) return "always";
```

One final side note -- as I stumbled upon this question looking for why iOS was having issues asking for permission. When asking for location permission on iOS, be sure to ask for either `locationWhenInUse` or `locationAlways` specifically. Android allows you to ask for general location permission (`Permission.location.request()` instead of, say `Permission.locationAlways.request()`) but I found that the former fails for iOS without notice.
Hopefully this helps save somebody some time somewhere.